# Selenium IntelliJ Maven Chrome SessionNotCreated Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, selenium-chromedriver, webdrivermanager-java

My Chrome Browser on the test machine has been updated to 122.0.6261.70 but has stopped my tests working with the error,

> SessionNotCreated Could not start a new session. Possible causes are
> invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

I am using the bonigarcia webdrivermanager dependency 5.7.0, in my Maven project to manage the Webdriver, but cannot for the life of me figure out how do fix the error that the session can't be started.

This is the code to launch the browser

'''
@BeforeTest
public void LaunchBrowser() {

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.http.factory", "jdk-http-client");

    // Chrome browser setup
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

   //Call getDownloadedDriverPath() to rerieve the path
   String downloadedDriverPath = getDownloadedDriverPath();
   System.out.println("Downloaded driver path: " + downloadedDriverPath);

   // Call getDownloadedDriverPath() to retrieve the version
   String downloadedDriverVersion = getDownloadedDriverVersion();
   System.out.println("Downloaded driver version: " + downloadedDriverVersion);

    // Configure Chrome options
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");

    // Initialize ChromeDriver with options
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    // Define an array of possible options
    String[] paths = {
            "App1",
            "App2",
            "App3"
    };

    // Get a random option from the array
    Random rand = new Random();
    selectedPath = paths[rand.nextInt(paths.length)];
    // Get the corresponding app name for the selected path
    appName = getAppName(selectedPath);
    // Use the appName variable in other parts of the test
    System.out.println("Selected App: " + appName);

    driver.get("https://portal-test.homeapphub.com/anonymous/signup/" + selectedPath);
}
```

'''

Here is my output, running Selenium Java 4.18.1

'''

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenText\UFT One\bin\java_shared\classes\jasmine.jar"
[INFO] Running TestSuite
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Downloaded driver path: null
Downloaded driver version: null
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest RPSPortal.LaunchBrowser
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Host info: host: 'WILSON-GAMING', ip: '169.254.54.228'
Build info: version: '4.18.1', revision: 'b1d3319b48'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '21.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

'''

Comment: I have added this to my code  // Call getDownloadedDriverPath() to retrieve the path
        String downloadedDriverPath = getDownloadedDriverPath();
        System.out.println("Downloaded driver path: " + downloadedDriverPath);

        // Call getDownloadedDriverPath() to retrieve the version
        String downloadedDriverVersion = getDownloadedDriverVersion();
        System.out.println("Downloaded driver version: " + downloadedDriverVersion); but they both return null. Is it because the driver isn't available to the Web DriverManager yet?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I was missing the following dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-http</artifactId>
            <version>4.18.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Adding that in has resolved it although not sure why it ran before without that.